# Swift - use a function like .first on an array, but to get the second element

Tags: swift

I use .first to receive elements from an array. When the array is empty, it returns a standard value:

```
plant.waterEventArrayDetailed.first?.plantRating ?? 0
```

I would like to acces the second value. But, sometimes the array is empty, so using a simple [1] would crash. How can I get the function to return the second value?

Comment: Why not create an extension on it, check if `count > 1`, and return the value or nil, something like: `extension Array { func second() -> Element? { count > 1 ? self[1] : nil } }`

Answer (score 4):

Now there is :)

```swift
extension Collection {
    var second: Element? { dropFirst().first }
}

print(["a", "b", "c"].second) // => Optional("b")
```

Answer (score -1):

Should've thought some more. You can drop the first element and then access the new first element:

```
plant.waterEventArrayDetailed.dropFirst().first?.plantRating ?? 0
```

Comment: Better to return `nil` than zero so it is clear that the array doesn't have a second element